# Javascript Regex Not Giving Multiple Results

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to read a string formatted like

```
<test>input</test>\n <another>input</another>
```

My regex works for the **test** tagged input, but ignores the **another** tagged input. If I wrap the entire regex in parenthesis and use the brackets {} to specify how many times, then it only saves the last match case. How can I catch and save all match cases?

My regex:

```
/([\n\s]*<([^>]+)>([^<>]*)<([^>]+)>[\n\s]*){0,}/
```

Result contents of match:

```
<test>input</test>\n <another>input</another>
<another>input</another>
another
input
/input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [g Modifier](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) so specify that it is global (allows for multiple results)

So change your regexp to (notice the g in the end)

```
/([\n\s]*<([^>]+)>([^<>]*)<([^>]+)>[\n\s]*){0,}/g
```

Comment: Turns out it gives me the expected result without the brackets and your suggestion. I cannot believe how simple it was. Thanks!